¿Cómo colocar unos degradados en el fondo de la pantalla en HTML y dónde colocar dicha etiqueta?
Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto en el que debo hacer funcional un juego de palabras y quisiera añadir un llamativo fondo a mi trabajo.

Podrías mostrar una imágen de lo que quieres y el código que intentaste?

Esa es una muy buena idea.

Por favor, añade código así como ejemplos de lo que necesitas para que podamos proveer una solución que se adapte a lo que ya tienes, pues hay distintas formas y escenarios para lograr lo que buscas.
